# Convert ImageSource to WriteableBitmap in Metro Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, writeablebitmap, imagesource

I was wondering how I could go about converting an `ImageSource` object (in my case the source property of an image element) to a `WriteableBitmap`. The `WriteableBitmap(BitmapSource)` constructor doesn't work in Windows 8 Metro, so I can't do that.

I've tried to load the `ImageSource` object into a stream and then use `WriteableBitmap.SetSource(stream)`, but I can't figure out how do load the image in a stream either.

```
InMemoryRandomAccessStream ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, ras);

byte[] pixelArray = new byte[(uint)photoBox.Height * (uint)photoBox.Width * 4];

enc.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
                 (uint)photoBox.Width, (uint)photoBox.Height, 96, 96, pixelArray);
```

I've also added this helper method I found online:

```
public Byte[] BufferFromImage(BitmapImage imageSource)
{
    Stream stream = imageSource.StreamSource;
    Byte[] buffer = null;
    if (stream != null && stream.Length > 0)
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            buffer = br.ReadBytes((Int32)stream.Length);
        }
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

The problem is that `BitmapImage` no longer has the `StreamSource` method.

Comment: Ooh - better edit this to remove the M-word... :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got an answer on the MSDN forums.

> There is no way to extract the image data from an ImageSource. You will need to keep track of the original source of the information and recreate the image in the WriteableBitmap from the original source. If you know you are going to need to do this you may be better off just using a WriteableBitmap as your ImageSource to begin with.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/c059b1f9-8a28-47c2-a259-3ab561c6e49a)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

The WinRT XAML platform has some unfortunate limitations in the bitmap classes. The [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) has a [FromBitmapImage](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/16916#309183) method you could look at. It basically takes the original source and loads the WriteableBitmap based on that source. Currently it is limited to bitmaps from where the application was installed, but this should be fairly easy to extend to files from the web (e.g. using the [WebFile](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/16916#309191) class to download the image). The only case where you would need to do some application-specific code would be if you loaded the BitmapImage using SetStream - where the original Uri would be lost, but in that case - you could just as well use a WriteableBitmap instead of the BitmapImage and copying pixels/bytes between WriteableBitmaps is possible.

Comment: This links for "WinRT XAML Toolkit" are dead. I think this is the same library: https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit